# Надо что-то делать с [google-maps] и [google-maps-api]

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток, описание-метки

[google-maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) (246 вопросов) и [google-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api) (499 вопросов). На en SO это синонимы, где основная метка [google-maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps).

[google-maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) короче, я бы предложил её сделать основной. Вот только с меткой [google-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api) в 2 раза больше вопросов. Если исходить из того, что api метку используют чаще, то её стоит сделать основной?

Что делать будем?

**UPD:** возможно, это разные метки. Тогда, как минимум, нужно поменять у них описание, а то сейчас оно полностью идентичное.

Comment: Я что-то не уверен, что это одно и то же.

Comment: @Qwertiy в контексте специфики SO я слабо себе представляю работу с картами без затрагивания api, если честно =/

Comment: @Qwertiy у них на данный момент даже описание почти идентичное. Если можете расписать, чем метки отличаются, то можно будет поменять описание меток, чтоб было понятно, что они обозначают.

Comment: Я не знаю, мне просто так кажется...

Comment: Можно разделить и властвовать - если в вопросе значится google-maps-api, то очевидно, что это касается google-maps. Поэтому можно ставить google-maps метку и метку api при надобности. Не знаю, имеется таковая или нет, лично мне кажется ее использование удобным.

Comment: @Jenssen "уточняющие" метки - зло. На этом сайте не просто так куча меток с дефисом внутри...

Comment: Если смотреть на первоисточник [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/). Рассуждая об API они в конце отправляют за справками, в том числе на **Stack Overflow **_Задайте вопрос с тегом_ `google-maps`. а раз уж они смешивают эти понятия... может и правда не стоит их особо разделять, IMHO

Comment: Может сделать их синонимами? Для google-maps синоним google-maps-api и для google-maps-api синоним google-maps

Comment: @Suvitruf Вот не надо, пожалуйста :-) Вы задали вопрос. Получили N голосов, а потом подменили смысл в **UPD**. Лучше вернуть вопрос как было (и голоса на нем будут обозначать важность темы). А вариванты решения давать ответами и голоса за них видеть по отдельности.

Comment: @Kromster я вопрос практически сразу обновил.

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё [google-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api), [google-maps-api-2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2), [google-maps-api-3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3).

В данном контексте, если используется [google-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api), то, вероятно, речь в целом про [google-maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps), а не конкретную версию.

Апаю тему и предлагаю [google-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api) синонимизировать к [google-maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps). Сделать [google-maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) основной.

Answer (score 0):

Оставить как есть, но поменять описание у [google-maps-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api) и [google-maps](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps).